# Custom Ansible Callback not receiving group_vars/host_vars

Tags: ansible, callback

I have a custom ansible callback that I am writing:

```py
class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):
    CALLBACK_VERSION = 2.0
    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'aggregate'
    CALLBACK_NAME = 'my_callback'

    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result):
        print("v2_runner_on_ok")
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        result._host.groups[0].get_vars()
```

When I inspect the contents of `result._host.groups[0].get_vars()`, it is returning `{}`, which is not what I expect. I have verified that the host is receiving `group_vars` (by placing a `debug` task in my playbook and printing out the expected var).  So my question is, why does the callback not receive the `group_vars` for the host?

On another equally strange note, the `host_vars` are not commuted to my callback plugin either. It would seem that the only vars that trickle into my plugin are the ones defined in the inventory file, and some magic vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing variables under `ansible.inventory` class hence you get only those defined in the inventory.

If you want to access other variables, you need to go through the play's variable manager:

```
def v2_playbook_on_play_start(self, play):
    variable_manager = play.get_variable_manager()
    hostvars = variable_manager.get_vars()['hostvars']
```

Answer (score 1):

Excellent @techraf helped me figure this out.  I needed to capture the Play's Variable Manager:

```
class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):
    CALLBACK_VERSION = 2.0
    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'aggregate'
    CALLBACK_NAME = 'is'

    def v2_playbook_on_play_start(self, play):
      self.vm = play.get_variable_manager()

    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result):
      host_vars = self.vm.get_vars()['hostvars'][result._host.name]
      var_that_i_want = host_vars['var_that_i_want']
```

Comment: I have marked @techraf answer as the correct one, but I will leave this one here for completeness